# Splitting a list of objects into n lists while keeping all attributes

Tags: python, list, class, object, oop

I'm trying to code a class method that takes every nth item and puts into a separate list. Then puts each of those lists into a separate object, all with the same attributes as the original object except for the lst attribute

For some reason when I run the program it only returns the first half of the inputted list

Here's the code

```
    def return_nfolds(self,num=3):
        j = 0
        lst = []
        while j < num:
            lst.append(self.lst[j:len(self.lst):num])
            j+=1
        objs = [copy.deepcopy(self) for i in range(len(lst))]
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            objs[i].lst = copy.deep(lst[i])
        return objs
```

I've tried the first half of the function, splitting the list, by itself(shown below) which works as expected but it doesn't work when I run the full code

```
j = 0
num = 2
test = list(range(100))
lst = []

while j<num:
    lst.append(test[j:len(test):num])
    j+=1
print(lst)
```

edit: update

I've tried the following code which works exactly as intended so I have no clue why the original isn't working

```
import copy
class listholder():
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.a)+str(self.b)+str(self.list)
j = 0
num = 2
test = list(range(100))
lst = []
obj = listholder()
obj.a = 0
obj.b = 1
while j<num:
    lst.append(test[j:len(test):num])
    j+=1
    objs = [copy.deepcopy(obj) for i in range(len(lst))]
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        objs[i].list = copy.deepcopy(lst[i])
print(*objs)
```

Comment: What is `copy.lst` ? That function is not defined on my copy of Python.

Comment: Nick ODell sorry that should say deep copy I've fixed it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution

If anyone is wondering there were actually 2 variables in the object that I needed to keep track of instead of one

the one I tracked here only held the object, there was another with all the string identifiers of the objects that I also needed to change